# Geotagging images in a folder with a reference csv

Tags: python, pandas, batch-processing, glob, exif

I want to add GPS information to the metadata of a bunch of jpg images in a folder with the use of Python.

The folder also contains a reference.csv looking like this:
[image]

The code I came up with so far looks like this:

```
## Exectute the script in the folder containing the image files

import glob
import pandas as pd
from exif import Image

# Import reference Data with columns of interest
df = pd.read_csv('reference.csv', delimiter='\s+', quotechar="'")
latitude = pd.read_csv('reference.csv', delimiter='\s+', quotechar="'", usecols=[2])
longitude = pd.read_csv('reference.csv', delimiter='\s+', quotechar="'", usecols=[3])

# store image files from the working directory in a list
images = [f for f in glob.glob("*.jpg")]

image = Image('pano_000004_000000.jpg')
image.gps_latitude = (latitude.iloc[1])
image.gps_longitute = (longitude.iloc[1])
dir(image)
```

For now I tried to write the info to one image (which didn't work). In the future I want to execute the script and write the missing GPS information into the corresponding image for all images in a batch process.
How can I edit my code so that it will take the gps-information from the reference file and write it into the corresponding images' metadata?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think you should be able to do that without needing to write any Python, just using `exiftool` along these lines, if you export the relevant columns, appropriately named, as a CSV. https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=12161.0

Comment: I tried the exiftool, but the timestamps are all over the place, so it didn't work.
If I put a string like "52.234" into the image.gps_latitude = (...) it does work. I would like to take those values from the reference.csv though.

Answer (score 0):

try to use gpsphoto

```
from GPSPhoto import gpsphoto
photo = gpsphoto.GPSPhoto("image.jpg")
info  = gpsphoto.GPSInfo((float('55.555555'),float('33.333333')),timeStamp='2022:01:11 11:11:11')
photo.modGPSData(info, "image_with_gps.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested my solution for this task looks as follows:

```
# Import reference Data with columns of interest
            df = pd.read_csv(
                f"{image_dir}/reference.csv",
                delimiter="\s+",
                quotechar="'",
                usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 10],
                )
            df = df.rename(
                columns={
                    "gps_seconds[s]": "GPSDateTime",
                    "file_name": "SourceFile",
                    "latitude[deg]": "GPSLatitude",
                    "longitude[deg]": "GPSLongitude",
                    "projectedZ[m]": "GPSAltitude",
                    }
                )
                
            # Replace content of 'SourceFile' column with absolute filepaths
            df["SourceFile"] = df["SourceFile"].apply(
                lambda x: pathlib.Path(image_dir, x + ".jpg").absolute()
                )
                
            # Date and time
            df.update(df[["SourceFile"]].applymap('"{}"'.format))
            df["GPSDateTime"] = df.apply(lambda x: gps_to_unix(x["GPSDateTime"]), axis=1)
            df["GPSDateStamp"] = pd.to_datetime(
                df["GPSDateTime"], unit="s"
                ).dt.strftime("%Y:%m:%d")
            df["GPSTimeStamp"] = pd.to_datetime(
                df["GPSDateTime"], unit="s"
                ).dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
            
            # Lat, lon, alt reference
            df["GPSLatitudeRef"] = "N"
            df["GPSLongitudeRef"] = "E"
            df["GPSAltitudeRef"] = "above"
                
            # Save df to .csv file        
            df.to_csv(
                f"{image_dir}/reference_geotag.csv", index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE
                )
                
            # Exiftool command creation and execution
            stmt_exif = f"""
            exiftool -overwrite_original -csv="{image_dir}/reference_geotag.csv" -geotag="{image_dir}/reference_geotag.csv" "{image_dir}"
            """
            os.system(stmt_exif)
```